# Find polygon overlaps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to find polygon overlaps and get their geometry. Does anybody have idea how to do that?

This is polygon table:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
  id varchar(32),
  shape geometry);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('California', geometry::Parse('POLYGON((-124.23 41.96, -119.97 41.93, -119.97 38.99, -113.95 34.30, -114.69 32.62, -117.11 32.43, -122.25 36.10, -124.23 41.96))')),
('Western US', geometry::Parse('POLYGON((-124.71 48.69, -102.97 48.86, -102.88 31.72, -117.15 32.39, -124.01 39.50, -124.71 48.69))')),
('US', geometry::Parse('POLYGON((-124.62 48.86, -94.57 48.98, -80.68 42.09, -66.88 45.02, -82.26 28.69, -98.96 26.90, -116.80 32.62, -124.36 39.77, -124.62 48.86))')),
('Colorado', geometry::Parse('POLYGON((-108.98 40.91, -108.98 36.87, -101.95 36.87, -101.95 40.91, -108.98 40.91))'));
```

Comment: What do you mean by polygon overlaps?

Comment: Intersections between this polygons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
    T.id
    , O.id
    , T.shape.STIntersection(O.shape) Intersection
FROM @Table T
INNER JOIN @Table O
    ON T.shape.STIntersects(T.shape) = 1
    AND T.id > O.id
```

Comment: I need the actual geometry of the intersection.

Comment: I'd use `T.id > O.id` to avoid having duplicated results. (I'm assuming that `A.STIntersection(B) = B.STIntersection(A)`)

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, I didn't think of that, very good point. I just tried it and got the same spatial results, so I assume that `T.id <> O.id` was returning duplicates. I'll make that edit.

Comment: @Nenad It should have what you need now, thanks to Martin S. :)

Comment: Thanks man!! Is it possible to make this code more efficient because it is very time-consuming for biger set of data

Comment: @Nenad Not that I know of, though there may be some trick out there. This will never compare the exact same set of rows to each other, so I'm not thinking of any way to limit it more without missing some valid comparisons. Take that with a grain of salt though as I'm not the best on perf and this is the first time I've done anything with the `GEOMETRY` type.

Comment: I thought that spatial indexes were supposed to help with intersects queries.  Try putting an index on your geometry column and see how it goes.