# Spatial intersection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, geospatial, intersection, spatial

I am running a LAMP stack and would like to do some advanced spatial queries. Does anyone have a solution for finding the shape of the intersection of two polygons? I am aware that currently MySQL doesn't support the intersection function but I was hoping that someone may have their own intersection function or another solution.

If it makes is any clearer, this would be the equivalent in MSSQL

```
SELECT
      T1.id,
      T2.id,
      T1.shape.STIntersection(T2.shape) Intersection

FROM
      table1 T1
      INNER JOIN table2 T2
      ON T1.shape.STIntersects(T1.shape) = 1
      AND T1.id > T2.id
```

Thanks to the
[Find polygon overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079879/find-polygon-overlaps) post.

Answer (score -2):

> I am aware that currently MySQL doesn't support the intersection function

[Really?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-create-new-geometries-from-existing-ones.html#function_intersection)

Comment: As far as I am aware "These functions are not implemented in MySQL."

Comment: I had already checked the MySQL documentation before posting and it states. The  Intersection(g1,g2) function is **"not implemented in MySQL"**. Intersection(g1,g2) is a proposed function from OpenGIS. Am I missing something obvious? Am I able to implement OpenGIS functions in MySQL?